# Add custom properties to Serilog

Tags: c#, serilog

I'm using Serilog with an MS SQL Server sink in my application. Let's assume I have defined the following class ...

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
  // ... more properties
}
```

... and created an instance:

```
var person = new Person
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    BirthDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-25)
};
```

I have placed the following log call in my code:

```
Log.Information("New user: {FirstName:l} {LastName:l}",
    person.FirstName, person.LastName);
```

Is it possible to also log the `BirthDate` property *without adding it to the message template* so that it's rendered within the `Properties` XML column? I'd like to output it later in a details view of my application's log viewer.

I'm basically looking for a behavior similar to the object destructuring, but without printing the flat object as part of the log message.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is as simple as:

```
Log.ForContext("BirthDate", person.BirthDate)
   .Information("New user: {FirstName:l} {LastName:l}",
                           person.FirstName, person.LastName);
```

Comment: I see, that's pretty simple. Does that method also allow for destructuring of objects that have a complex type (such as a *Father* property of type `Person`)? I'm more interested in the properties' values than the `ToString()` representation.

Comment: Absolutely - `Log.ForContext("Father", father, destructureObjects: true)` does that.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. I read the manual, but I must have somehow overlooked that. Thank you!

Answer (score 37):

You can actually do this in a few different ways. In your case, the first way is probably the best:

```cs
Log.ForContext("BirthDate", person.BirthDate)
    .Information("New user: {FirstName:l} {LastName:l}",
        person.FirstName, person.LastName);
```

But you can also use the `LogContext` in other scenarios:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    // Enrich all log entries with properties from LogContext
    .Enrich.FromLogContext();

using (LogContext.PushProperty("BirthDate", person.BirthDate))
{
    Log.Information("New user: {FirstName:l} {LastName:l}",
        person.FirstName, person.LastName);
}
```

Or, in the case where you want to log a "constant" property, you can add it like this:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    // Enrich all log entries with property
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", "My Application");
```

See [Context and correlation – structured logging concepts in .NET (5)](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/08/context-and-correlation-structured-logging-concepts-in-net-5/) for more information.

Comment: `.Enrich.FromLogContext()` is the call I was missing to make my property-based filtering work!

Answer (score 18):

If you're using the generic Microsoft ILogger interface you can use BeginScope;

```
using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "LogEventType", logEventType }, { "UserName",  userName } }))
{
    _logger.LogInformation(message, args);
}
```

This is discussed here; https://blog.rsuter.com/logging-with-ilogger-recommendations-and-best-practices/