# How can I add a named property that is not part of the message template?

Tags: serilog

In some cases, I would like to **add contextual information to a message** (for instance currently authenticated user), **without having to include it in the message template**.

I would like to accomplish this :

```
logger.Information("Doing stuff {Foo} with the thing {Bar}. {User}", foo, bar, user)
```

but without the `{User}` in the template.

I already know about [`LogContext`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#the-logcontext) but that seems overkill when adding contextual information to just one event.

I also know I can use the low-level API `logger.Write(LogEvent evnt)` to actually control which properties are included, but that seems like a bit too much code for what I am trying to accomplish.

I'm pretty sure there is a short and elegant way that is super obvious, but I haven't found it :)

**UPDATE :**

I found out only afterwards that this question is more or less similar : [Add custom properties to Serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888715/add-custom-properties-to-serilog)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add custom properties to Serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888715/add-custom-properties-to-serilog)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could figure it out on my own!

You can use the fluent method `.ForContext(propertyName, propertyValue)` on a single call to one of the `.LogXXX()` methods.

For instance :

```
logger.ForContext("User", user)
      .Information("Doing stuff {Foo} with the thing {Bar}", foo, bar)
```

The property added to the event only apply to the event, and they are no longer present on the next call to the `logger.LogXXX()` method

**UPDATE**

The article by Nicholas Blumhardt explains it quite well : [Context and correlation – structured logging concepts in .NET (5)](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/08/context-and-correlation-structured-logging-concepts-in-net-5/)

Comment: I'll have to look over my notes, but IIRC, this Serilog context gets lost across an AsyncState transition.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using the generic Microsoft ILogger you can use BeginScope;

```
using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "LogEventType", logEventType }, { "UserName",  userName } }))
{
    _logger.LogInformation(message, args);
}
```

This is discussed here; https://blog.rsuter.com/logging-with-ilogger-recommendations-and-best-practices/

Comment: Not sure why this isn't upvoted more. I would prefer to use ILogger interface than be tightly coupled to Serilog (although Serilog is awesome).

Comment: Even though the question has a #serilog tag, this approach may be more preferable, since, as mentioned by @triple.vee, it removes the need to hard-wire Serilog dependency into your logging code.

Comment: This adds the property to the properties object, is it possible to have as an independent property?

Comment: As cool as Serilog is, I too prefer ILogger. I am in the process of switching to Serilog from Log4Net and am glad I used a façade for Log4Net, so the switch is easier. Ilogger serves the same purpose as my façade did.