# How to unit test Serilog calls when using ForContext

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, serilog

I'm using the `ForContext()` method of Serilog to add custom properties to the log event as per the [general guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637416/how-can-i-add-a-named-property-that-is-not-part-of-the-message-template)

The problem with this is that from what I can see in the source code, calling ForContext() does this:

```cs
    ILogger ForContext(string propertyName, object? value, bool destructureObjects = false)
        => new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Is(LevelAlias.Minimum)
            .WriteTo.Logger(this)
            .CreateLogger()
            .ForContext(propertyName, value, destructureObjects)
    ;
```

which returns a new object, so when I chain these calls and I try to write unit tests to assert that ForContext was called for each property and the appropriate log method was called it always fails. For example:

```cs
public class MyService
{
  ILogger _logger;  

  public MyService (ILogger log)
  {
    _logger = log
  }


  public void DoStuff()
  {
    _logger
        .ForContext("One", 1)
        .ForContext("Two", 2)
        .Warning("Not happy");
  }
}
```

and the following example test:

```cs
public class MyServiceTest
{
  Mock<ILogger> _loggerMock = new();  
  MyService sut;

  public MyServiceTest(ILogger log)
  {
   _loggerMock.Setup(x => x.Warning(It.IsAny<string>()).Verifiable();
    sut = new MyService(_loggerMock.Object);
  }


  public void DoStuffShouldLogWarning()
  {
     sut.DoStuff();
    _loggerMock.Verify(x => x.Warning(It.IsAny<string>()), times.once);
  }
}
```

I get that Warning was never called but that `ForContext("One", 1)` was called once and then `Write()` was called....which is basically true.

How can I do this in a way that allows me to make sure some other developer (or me) didn't just random remove a property from the log, or use the wrong value, or change the log level as part of a code change.

Comment: could you not set up the mock object to handle `ForContext` calls?

Comment: Make your mock strict? So that it fails when things get called you didn't set up?  That should make test fail when people implemented things that a test doesn't expect.

Comment: @JeanotZubler that's a fair shout actually and not sure why I didn't think about that. Although its kinda annoying that you HAVE to do that.... still, beggars can't be choosers and we don't pay for Serilog.

Comment: @Ralf I'm not sure how that would help me in this situation. The problem is that the test fails when it shouldn't. Could you give an example.

Comment: Your examples shows using Error but you are testing for Warning. And to detect those errors (something is called you didn't expect) strict mock help. They will bark on everything that was called but wasn't mocked. It would have also told you that you didn't Mock ForContext. And by fixing all those missing setups you get told by using a strict mock you will end typically with a good working test.

Comment: @Ralf - ha, yer sorry bad example code I updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the back of the comment from @Jeanot Zubler (thanks for pointing me in the right direction) based on my original example I solve it like this:

```cs
_mockLogger.Setup(x => x.ForContext(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(_mockLogger.Object);
```

you can then do this:

```cs
// Verify the for context call
_mockLogger.Verify(o => o.ForContext(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());
// Verify the chained warning
_loggerMock.Verify(x => x.Warning(It.IsAny<string>()), times.once);
```